# Attempt at displaying data results in graphql error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

Here's the code in my gatsby-node.js:

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch")

const NODE_TYPE = `objkt`

exports.sourceNodes = async ({
  actions,
  createContentDigest,
  createNodeId,
}) => {
  const { createNode } = actions

  const response = await fetch(
    "https://staging.api.tzkt.io/v1/bigmaps/523/keys?value.issuer=tz1V9ZviaGUWZjGx4U7cGYFEyUGyqpFnVGXx&active=true"
  )
  const objkt = await response.json()

  objkt.forEach((node, index) => {
    createNode({
      ...node,
      id: createNodeId(`${NODE_TYPE}-${node.id}`),
      parent: null,
      children: [],
      internal: {
        type: NODE_TYPE,
        content: JSON.stringify(node),
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(node),
      },
    })
  })
}

exports.onPreInit = () => console.log("Loaded gatsby-node")
```

This works fine when displaying the data through

```
{JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)}
```

Results in error when used in a gatsby .js page file.

Code in the gatsby page file:

```js
import React from "react"
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"

export const query = graphql`
  {
    allObjkt {
      edges {
        node {
          value {
            objkt_id
            xtz_per_objkt
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
export default ({ data }) => <>
  <h1>Punks on sale...</h1>
  <ul>
    {data.allObjkt.nodes.map(objkt => (
      <li key={objkt.id}>
        <h2>{objkt.xtz_per_objkt}</h2>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>

</>
```

Error produced:

```js
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

  20 |   <h1>Punks on sale...</h1>
  21 |   <ul>
> 22 |     {data.allObjkt.nodes.map(objkt => (
     |                         ^
  23 |       <li key={objkt.id}>
  24 |         <h2>{objkt.xtz_per_objkt}</h2>
  25 |       </li>
```

Some background, I'm using [this site](https://staging.api.tzkt.io/v1/bigmaps/523/keys?value.issuer=tz1V9ZviaGUWZjGx4U7cGYFEyUGyqpFnVGXx&active=true) to source my data. I've been getting this error for a while now and I don't know what is up with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. You are querying for `edges` and `node`, not `nodes`. So your code should look like:

```
export default ({ data }) => <>
  <h1>Punks on sale...</h1>
  <ul>
    {console.log("data is", data)}
    {data.allObjkt.edges.map(({node})=> {
     console.log("node", node);
     return <li key={node.value.objkt_id}>
        <h2>{node.value.xtz_per_objkt}</h2>
      </li>
    })}
  </ul>

</>
```

Comment: Above code results in the same error

"Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: Check again the code. Try printing your data in a console.log to see what's inside and if you are fetching properly the data.

Comment: This is odd, when adding "console.log('objkt', objkt)" in the gatsby-node.js file, everything prints out as expected yet the .js page that queries the data still throws the "cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: I had another typo, this time with "id"... the problem is fixed and it gets past all errors now!